# Why is the geojson data not being loaded?

Tags: google-maps, geojson

so here's my code snippet

```
function initMap() {
        var tempObject ={"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Gopi Krishna Cinema Hall"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.34531325101852,27.722718462967993]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"stroke":"#a87a6c","stroke-width":2,"stroke-opacity":1},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[85.34399092197418,27.722231727059405],[85.34412503242493,27.722317202790876],[85.34443080425262,27.722298208189677],[85.34483313560486,27.722188989168544],[85.34512281417845,27.72215099991813],[85.34523546695709,27.72216049723199],[85.34531593322754,27.722226978405697],[85.34535884857178,27.722307705490685],[85.34535348415375,27.722526143185743],[85.34529983997345,27.72274458044313],[85.3449296951294,27.723822514413428],[85.34484922885895,27.724107429100577],[85.34479558467865,27.724525302628134],[85.34483850002289,27.72485770088128],[85.34490287303925,27.725095127584463],[85.34526497125626,27.726258510955365],[85.34544602036476,27.726840197984977],[85.34588992595673,27.728281343907046],[85.34594893455504,27.72863272420807],[85.34595429897308,27.728865394324604],[85.345938205719,27.7291075606531],[85.34590601921082,27.72927850126692],[85.3458309173584,27.729430448254163],[85.34511744976044,27.730593785355854],[85.34470170736313,27.731268040359414],[85.34449383616447,27.731605166296973],[85.34356914460659,27.73302488239378],[85.34310679882765,27.733734733506658],[85.34204414114356,27.735383516994272],[85.34151256084442,27.736187126685248],[85.34124702215195,27.736609701929467],[85.34086212515831,27.737238813723312],[85.3404825925827,27.73785367796667],[85.3401231765747,27.738247759016165],[85.3395813703537,27.73866557833122],[85.33904492855072,27.738997933460364],[85.33877670764922,27.739149866896028],[85.3379961848259,27.739584300394576],[85.33760592341423,27.73980151649425],[85.3374107927084,27.739910124381677],[85.33731322735548,27.739964428284782],[85.33719688653946,27.740018732160838],[85.33714592456816,27.739994992764807],[85.33710837364197,27.739987870944983],[85.33705472946167,27.74000448852383],[85.33667251467705,27.73955343905567],[85.33648140728474,27.73932791362132],[85.33638585358858,27.739215150729088],[85.33624202013016,27.7390525345632],[85.33577665686606,27.738682196111764],[85.33484257757664,27.737917775583817],[85.33437553793192,27.737535563308704],[85.33370615914464,27.736970551402596],[85.333371469751,27.736688044350863],[85.33274949062616,27.736176443581986],[85.33243850106372,27.73592064229679],[85.33173583564349,27.735371350036857],[85.33138450293336,27.735096702868567],[85.33100366592407,27.734805436638784],[85.33070862293243,27.734520549914613],[85.33039212226868,27.73430213625503],[85.32963842153549,27.73367300750649],[85.3292615711689,27.733358441770193],[85.3290731459856,27.73320115856153],[85.32887935638428,27.733015386026484],[85.32924950122832,27.73217970246361],[85.32902419567108,27.731196816436352],[85.32962501049042,27.731044871911624],[85.33021241426468,27.73041572435939],[85.3305047750473,27.730099962143683],[85.33092319965363,27.72963462668467],[85.33085882663727,27.729397209868786],[85.33083736896515,27.729188282643047],[85.33093392848969,27.728737188403464],[85.33083200454712,27.72751685042005],[85.33070862293243,27.72700876793183],[85.33057451248169,27.726443701448524],[85.33060133457184,27.726339235055185],[85.33067107200623,27.72620152920188],[85.33082664012909,27.72485295234194],[85.33096075057982,27.724553793946694],[85.33107876777649,27.724363851682373],[85.33110558986664,27.72413117195756],[85.33106803894043,27.723718045508267],[85.33109486103058,27.723171956420096],[85.33117532730103,27.722986760369107],[85.33126652240753,27.722711340019146],[85.3313684463501,27.722136753945836],[85.33140063285828,27.721600154300003],[85.33161520957947,27.720921090785584],[85.33160448074341,27.720645665217553],[85.3313684463501,27.72000933452063],[85.33119678497314,27.719453729308267],[85.33093392848969,27.718679676301594],[85.33040285110474,27.717145800430824],[85.33027410507202,27.71657118502949],[85.32999515533446,27.715801860495628],[85.3297108411789,27.715084769160644],[85.32951235771178,27.71454813481229],[85.32941579818726,27.7144958959294],[85.32713055610657,27.714885312454545],[85.326851606369,27.71494704909303],[85.3267389535904,27.714961296004635],[85.32654047012329,27.71494704909303],[85.32633125782013,27.714928053207984],[85.32619178295135,27.71487581450705],[85.32611131668091,27.714795081920055],[85.32603085041046,27.71469535334769],[85.32596647739409,27.714500644919788],[85.32583236694336,27.714239450141335],[85.32578408718108,27.71418246210656],[85.3256767988205,27.71413022304851],[85.32535493373871,27.714063736938428],[85.32519400119781,27.713987752763018],[85.32500624656677,27.71381203915463],[85.32462000846863,27.7131614214373],[85.32494187355042,27.713284896630924],[85.32507598400116,27.71335613225598],[85.32507598400116,27.71349385433251],[85.32500624656677,27.71380729013424],[85.32482385635376,27.71350810143393],[85.32462537288666,27.71317091953408],[85.32346665859222,27.71272450809126],[85.32216846942902,27.712149869395468],[85.32345592975616,27.71272450809126],[85.32462000846863,27.713166170485778],[85.32397091388701,27.713232657142992],[85.32314479351042,27.713679066506035],[85.3229570388794,27.713717058707896],[85.32197535037994,27.713717058707896],[85.32212018966675,27.712653272053693],[85.32222211360931,27.71159897325804],[85.321986079216,27.710568410082058],[85.321986079216,27.710478175976338],[85.32222211360931,27.7103119550599],[85.32203435897827,27.70921251604891],[85.32194048166275,27.708662792388186],[85.32189354300499,27.70838792951903],[85.32187007367611,27.708250497824753],[85.32185833901167,27.708181781912668],[85.32186269760132,27.708056074721792],[85.3218948841095,27.70798008636143],[85.32258689403534,27.707186954690865],[85.32271027565002,27.70704447533672],[85.32282829284668,27.706778513377774],[85.32288730144501,27.706555294804694],[85.32288730144501,27.705852390782685],[85.32287657260895,27.70558642591778],[85.32253861427307,27.70329957626455],[85.32236963510513,27.702156133464683],[85.32228514552116,27.70158440757158],[85.32224290072918,27.701298543501757],[85.32221138477325,27.701036426567757],[85.32298922538757,27.700889189599366],[85.32363831996918,27.700718204483533],[85.32392799854279,27.700618463042257],[85.32426595687866,27.700395231867134],[85.32448053359985,27.7003049893476],[85.32538712024689,27.700148252162602],[85.32572507858275,27.700143502547423],[85.32600402832031,27.700110255235376],[85.32648146152496,27.69998201550827],[85.32740414142609,27.69977065711073],[85.32869696617126,27.69946905509303],[85.32888472080231,27.699393060752385],[85.32891154289246,27.699269569835955],[85.32869964838028,27.698557119512728],[85.3285950422287,27.698200892607037],[85.32811224460602,27.696500486823165],[85.32769918441771,27.695061295866054],[85.32761335372925,27.69475255606003],[85.32762408256531,27.69440581646757],[85.32770991325378,27.694111324441874],[85.32772600650787,27.694035326370795],[85.32760262489319,27.693527087910365],[85.32754361629486,27.69335134135008],[85.32753825187682,27.69325634309158],[85.32780110836029,27.693066346326574],[85.32800763845444,27.692971347820066],[85.32817661762238,27.692890599024533],[85.32834291458128,27.692786100494594],[85.32846093177795,27.692714851439554],[85.32857894897461,27.69266260210297],[85.32941043376921,27.692391855140137],[85.329729616642,27.692315855871975],[85.33109486103058,27.691997608361884],[85.33178150653839,27.691807609406137],[85.33218383789062,27.691703109839512],[85.33289730548859,27.691437110491314],[85.33312797546387,27.69134686056521],[85.3334230184555,27.69131836057305],[85.3337287902832,27.69124236055756],[85.33405601978302,27.691128360435155],[85.3348982334137,27.690748359167333],[85.33582091331482,27.690373106617415],[85.33595502376556,27.690287605855996],[85.33555269241333,27.688325819992773],[85.3375107049942,27.68789355735167],[85.33975571393967,27.687387665384108],[85.3408782184124,27.68713471852137],[85.34234873950481,27.686801611547644],[85.34457262605429,27.686290667414433],[85.34568456932902,27.68603519445128],[85.34617885015905,27.685921708448795],[85.34702181816101,27.685675215554415],[85.34727931022644,27.68555170911927],[85.34764409065247,27.685309446090766],[85.34796059131622,27.685062432253385],[85.34830391407012,27.684758414455757],[85.34861505031586,27.684430644319534],[85.34889936447144,27.68404111911028],[85.34918904304504,27.68350908243325],[85.34926414489746,27.683271565222725],[85.34944117069244,27.682734774424002],[85.34951090812683,27.68164693365221],[85.34958064556122,27.680233674546376],[85.34961551427841,27.679527038135966],[85.34963294863701,27.679173718216415],[85.34963965415955,27.67882989823954],[85.3491300344467,27.678497359753933],[85.34833073616028,27.678055557057107],[85.3477030992508,27.677685011481945],[85.34742951393127,27.677480735819717],[85.34582018852234,27.67640234401577],[85.34501552581787,27.67586314412168],[85.34459710121155,27.675599481530597],[85.34359395503998,27.67480611458053],[85.34282147884369,27.674036495626662],[85.3426605463028,27.673863093076964],[85.3424996137619,27.673670687186004],[85.3423547744751,27.67370869331478],[85.34217238426208,27.673637431812473],[85.341979265213,27.673627930275323],[85.3418183326721,27.67368493948585],[85.34133553504942,27.673941480565038]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Balkumari"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.3413462638855,27.673912976030437]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Sukedhara"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.34576654434203,27.727830245914127]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Dhumbarahi Chowk"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.3441572189331,27.732103730912865]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Chappal Karkhana"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.34212946891785,27.73517104017694]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Bhabhateni, Maharajgunj"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33869624137877,27.739187850221853]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Narayangopal Chowk"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33656120300292,27.739282808478443]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Chundevi"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33424377441405,27.737412115579346]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"T.U Teaching Hospital"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33091247081757,27.73470572637005]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Nepal Police Academy","description":"Talimkedra"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.3289544582367,27.73283970308218]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Pabitra Workshop"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33086955547333,27.729686858314775]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Russian Embassy"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33093392848969,27.728727691662566]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"3. No Gate","description":"Baluwataar"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33068180084229,27.726116056515774]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Baluwataar"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.3309178352356,27.724646390680565]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Bhabhateni"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33125579357147,27.7196436801267]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Police Headquarter"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33039212226868,27.71709356279219]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Balmandir"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.3294587135315,27.714514891889714]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Naxal"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32667994499207,27.714942300122082]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Naag Pokhari"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32485604286194,27.71359833303317]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Manakamana Marg"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32376706600189,27.7128384856546]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Hattisar"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.3221845626831,27.71197890192642]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Hattisar/Kamalpokhari"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32202363014221,27.710734630607693]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Putalisadak"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32288193702698,27.706498302755374]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"New Plaza"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32273173332214,27.700936685417314]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"New Plaza"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32376170158386,27.700675458162724]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32889544963837,27.699340814612487]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Hanumansthan"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32753825187682,27.693284842577803]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Bhatbhateni, Anamnagar"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.32877743244171,27.69259610291114]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Baneswor","description":"In fron of BICC Hall"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33566266298294,27.690432482106786]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Sankhamul"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33609986305237,27.68820469162307]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Minbhawan"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.33864796161652,27.68762279856196]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Koteswor"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.34891009330748,27.678369094638953]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"marker-color":"#7e7e7e","marker-size":"medium","marker-symbol":"","name":"Nepal Yatayat Station, Chabahil"},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[85.34401774406433,27.722207983788774]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"stroke":"#a87a6c","stroke-width":2,"stroke-opacity":1,"type":"return"},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[85.32500088214874,27.71380729013424],[85.32499015331268,27.714158717083265],[85.32500088214874,27.714443657021473],[85.32504916191101,27.714742843155406],[85.3251564502716,27.715094267089952],[85.32527983188628,27.715284225502],[85.32539784908295,27.715417196193584],[85.32594501972197,27.715212991136262],[85.32620251178741,27.715127509835945],[85.32654583454132,27.715037279501804],[85.32680869102478,27.714956547034323]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"stroke":"#a87a6c","stroke-width":2,"stroke-opacity":1,"type":"return"},"geometry":{"type":"LineString","coordinates":[[85.3271359205246,27.714890061427965],[85.32750606536865,27.71631474412121],[85.3278923034668,27.71774415705227],[85.32858967781067,27.717611189197914],[85.32950699329376,27.717350001869082],[85.33039748668669,27.717112558300027]]}}]};

       var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.722718462967993,85.34531325101852),
          zoom: 13
        });
            var jsObject = tempObject.features;

            for(i=0;i<jsObject.length;i++){

                var geometry=jsObject[i].geometry;

                var coordinates = geometry.coordinates;

                for(j=0;j<coordinates.length;j++){      
                        var x=coordinates[j][0];
                        var y = coordinates[j][1];
                        //alert("Before "+tempObject.features[i].geometry.coordinates[j][0]);
                        tempObject.features[i].geometry.coordinates[j][0]=y;
                        tempObject.features[i].geometry.coordinates[j][1]=x;
                        //alert("After "+tempObject.features[i].geometry.coordinates[j][0]);
                }
      }
        console.log("tempObject "+tempObject.features[0].geometry.coordinates[0][0]);
        map.data.loadGeoJson(tempObject);
      }
```

But somehow the geojson data doesnt get loaded in the map. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. remove the loop, the data in `tempObject` seems to be correct as it is
2. use `addGeoJson` instead of `loadGeoJson`( use `loadGeoJson` when you request the data from external files)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.722718462967993, 85.34531325101852),
    zoom: 13
  });
  map.data.addGeoJson(tempObject);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
var tempObject = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Gopi Krishna Cinema Hall"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.34531325101852, 27.722718462967993]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "stroke": "#a87a6c",
      "stroke-width": 2,
      "stroke-opacity": 1
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [85.34399092197418, 27.722231727059405],
        [85.34412503242493, 27.722317202790876],
        [85.34443080425262, 27.722298208189677],
        [85.34483313560486, 27.722188989168544],
        [85.34512281417845, 27.72215099991813],
        [85.34523546695709, 27.72216049723199],
        [85.34531593322754, 27.722226978405697],
        [85.34535884857178, 27.722307705490685],
        [85.34535348415375, 27.722526143185743],
        [85.34529983997345, 27.72274458044313],
        [85.3449296951294, 27.723822514413428],
        [85.34484922885895, 27.724107429100577],
        [85.34479558467865, 27.724525302628134],
        [85.34483850002289, 27.72485770088128],
        [85.34490287303925, 27.725095127584463],
        [85.34526497125626, 27.726258510955365],
        [85.34544602036476, 27.726840197984977],
        [85.34588992595673, 27.728281343907046],
        [85.34594893455504, 27.72863272420807],
        [85.34595429897308, 27.728865394324604],
        [85.345938205719, 27.7291075606531],
        [85.34590601921082, 27.72927850126692],
        [85.3458309173584, 27.729430448254163],
        [85.34511744976044, 27.730593785355854],
        [85.34470170736313, 27.731268040359414],
        [85.34449383616447, 27.731605166296973],
        [85.34356914460659, 27.73302488239378],
        [85.34310679882765, 27.733734733506658],
        [85.34204414114356, 27.735383516994272],
        [85.34151256084442, 27.736187126685248],
        [85.34124702215195, 27.736609701929467],
        [85.34086212515831, 27.737238813723312],
        [85.3404825925827, 27.73785367796667],
        [85.3401231765747, 27.738247759016165],
        [85.3395813703537, 27.73866557833122],
        [85.33904492855072, 27.738997933460364],
        [85.33877670764922, 27.739149866896028],
        [85.3379961848259, 27.739584300394576],
        [85.33760592341423, 27.73980151649425],
        [85.3374107927084, 27.739910124381677],
        [85.33731322735548, 27.739964428284782],
        [85.33719688653946, 27.740018732160838],
        [85.33714592456816, 27.739994992764807],
        [85.33710837364197, 27.739987870944983],
        [85.33705472946167, 27.74000448852383],
        [85.33667251467705, 27.73955343905567],
        [85.33648140728474, 27.73932791362132],
        [85.33638585358858, 27.739215150729088],
        [85.33624202013016, 27.7390525345632],
        [85.33577665686606, 27.738682196111764],
        [85.33484257757664, 27.737917775583817],
        [85.33437553793192, 27.737535563308704],
        [85.33370615914464, 27.736970551402596],
        [85.333371469751, 27.736688044350863],
        [85.33274949062616, 27.736176443581986],
        [85.33243850106372, 27.73592064229679],
        [85.33173583564349, 27.735371350036857],
        [85.33138450293336, 27.735096702868567],
        [85.33100366592407, 27.734805436638784],
        [85.33070862293243, 27.734520549914613],
        [85.33039212226868, 27.73430213625503],
        [85.32963842153549, 27.73367300750649],
        [85.3292615711689, 27.733358441770193],
        [85.3290731459856, 27.73320115856153],
        [85.32887935638428, 27.733015386026484],
        [85.32924950122832, 27.73217970246361],
        [85.32902419567108, 27.731196816436352],
        [85.32962501049042, 27.731044871911624],
        [85.33021241426468, 27.73041572435939],
        [85.3305047750473, 27.730099962143683],
        [85.33092319965363, 27.72963462668467],
        [85.33085882663727, 27.729397209868786],
        [85.33083736896515, 27.729188282643047],
        [85.33093392848969, 27.728737188403464],
        [85.33083200454712, 27.72751685042005],
        [85.33070862293243, 27.72700876793183],
        [85.33057451248169, 27.726443701448524],
        [85.33060133457184, 27.726339235055185],
        [85.33067107200623, 27.72620152920188],
        [85.33082664012909, 27.72485295234194],
        [85.33096075057982, 27.724553793946694],
        [85.33107876777649, 27.724363851682373],
        [85.33110558986664, 27.72413117195756],
        [85.33106803894043, 27.723718045508267],
        [85.33109486103058, 27.723171956420096],
        [85.33117532730103, 27.722986760369107],
        [85.33126652240753, 27.722711340019146],
        [85.3313684463501, 27.722136753945836],
        [85.33140063285828, 27.721600154300003],
        [85.33161520957947, 27.720921090785584],
        [85.33160448074341, 27.720645665217553],
        [85.3313684463501, 27.72000933452063],
        [85.33119678497314, 27.719453729308267],
        [85.33093392848969, 27.718679676301594],
        [85.33040285110474, 27.717145800430824],
        [85.33027410507202, 27.71657118502949],
        [85.32999515533446, 27.715801860495628],
        [85.3297108411789, 27.715084769160644],
        [85.32951235771178, 27.71454813481229],
        [85.32941579818726, 27.7144958959294],
        [85.32713055610657, 27.714885312454545],
        [85.326851606369, 27.71494704909303],
        [85.3267389535904, 27.714961296004635],
        [85.32654047012329, 27.71494704909303],
        [85.32633125782013, 27.714928053207984],
        [85.32619178295135, 27.71487581450705],
        [85.32611131668091, 27.714795081920055],
        [85.32603085041046, 27.71469535334769],
        [85.32596647739409, 27.714500644919788],
        [85.32583236694336, 27.714239450141335],
        [85.32578408718108, 27.71418246210656],
        [85.3256767988205, 27.71413022304851],
        [85.32535493373871, 27.714063736938428],
        [85.32519400119781, 27.713987752763018],
        [85.32500624656677, 27.71381203915463],
        [85.32462000846863, 27.7131614214373],
        [85.32494187355042, 27.713284896630924],
        [85.32507598400116, 27.71335613225598],
        [85.32507598400116, 27.71349385433251],
        [85.32500624656677, 27.71380729013424],
        [85.32482385635376, 27.71350810143393],
        [85.32462537288666, 27.71317091953408],
        [85.32346665859222, 27.71272450809126],
        [85.32216846942902, 27.712149869395468],
        [85.32345592975616, 27.71272450809126],
        [85.32462000846863, 27.713166170485778],
        [85.32397091388701, 27.713232657142992],
        [85.32314479351042, 27.713679066506035],
        [85.3229570388794, 27.713717058707896],
        [85.32197535037994, 27.713717058707896],
        [85.32212018966675, 27.712653272053693],
        [85.32222211360931, 27.71159897325804],
        [85.321986079216, 27.710568410082058],
        [85.321986079216, 27.710478175976338],
        [85.32222211360931, 27.7103119550599],
        [85.32203435897827, 27.70921251604891],
        [85.32194048166275, 27.708662792388186],
        [85.32189354300499, 27.70838792951903],
        [85.32187007367611, 27.708250497824753],
        [85.32185833901167, 27.708181781912668],
        [85.32186269760132, 27.708056074721792],
        [85.3218948841095, 27.70798008636143],
        [85.32258689403534, 27.707186954690865],
        [85.32271027565002, 27.70704447533672],
        [85.32282829284668, 27.706778513377774],
        [85.32288730144501, 27.706555294804694],
        [85.32288730144501, 27.705852390782685],
        [85.32287657260895, 27.70558642591778],
        [85.32253861427307, 27.70329957626455],
        [85.32236963510513, 27.702156133464683],
        [85.32228514552116, 27.70158440757158],
        [85.32224290072918, 27.701298543501757],
        [85.32221138477325, 27.701036426567757],
        [85.32298922538757, 27.700889189599366],
        [85.32363831996918, 27.700718204483533],
        [85.32392799854279, 27.700618463042257],
        [85.32426595687866, 27.700395231867134],
        [85.32448053359985, 27.7003049893476],
        [85.32538712024689, 27.700148252162602],
        [85.32572507858275, 27.700143502547423],
        [85.32600402832031, 27.700110255235376],
        [85.32648146152496, 27.69998201550827],
        [85.32740414142609, 27.69977065711073],
        [85.32869696617126, 27.69946905509303],
        [85.32888472080231, 27.699393060752385],
        [85.32891154289246, 27.699269569835955],
        [85.32869964838028, 27.698557119512728],
        [85.3285950422287, 27.698200892607037],
        [85.32811224460602, 27.696500486823165],
        [85.32769918441771, 27.695061295866054],
        [85.32761335372925, 27.69475255606003],
        [85.32762408256531, 27.69440581646757],
        [85.32770991325378, 27.694111324441874],
        [85.32772600650787, 27.694035326370795],
        [85.32760262489319, 27.693527087910365],
        [85.32754361629486, 27.69335134135008],
        [85.32753825187682, 27.69325634309158],
        [85.32780110836029, 27.693066346326574],
        [85.32800763845444, 27.692971347820066],
        [85.32817661762238, 27.692890599024533],
        [85.32834291458128, 27.692786100494594],
        [85.32846093177795, 27.692714851439554],
        [85.32857894897461, 27.69266260210297],
        [85.32941043376921, 27.692391855140137],
        [85.329729616642, 27.692315855871975],
        [85.33109486103058, 27.691997608361884],
        [85.33178150653839, 27.691807609406137],
        [85.33218383789062, 27.691703109839512],
        [85.33289730548859, 27.691437110491314],
        [85.33312797546387, 27.69134686056521],
        [85.3334230184555, 27.69131836057305],
        [85.3337287902832, 27.69124236055756],
        [85.33405601978302, 27.691128360435155],
        [85.3348982334137, 27.690748359167333],
        [85.33582091331482, 27.690373106617415],
        [85.33595502376556, 27.690287605855996],
        [85.33555269241333, 27.688325819992773],
        [85.3375107049942, 27.68789355735167],
        [85.33975571393967, 27.687387665384108],
        [85.3408782184124, 27.68713471852137],
        [85.34234873950481, 27.686801611547644],
        [85.34457262605429, 27.686290667414433],
        [85.34568456932902, 27.68603519445128],
        [85.34617885015905, 27.685921708448795],
        [85.34702181816101, 27.685675215554415],
        [85.34727931022644, 27.68555170911927],
        [85.34764409065247, 27.685309446090766],
        [85.34796059131622, 27.685062432253385],
        [85.34830391407012, 27.684758414455757],
        [85.34861505031586, 27.684430644319534],
        [85.34889936447144, 27.68404111911028],
        [85.34918904304504, 27.68350908243325],
        [85.34926414489746, 27.683271565222725],
        [85.34944117069244, 27.682734774424002],
        [85.34951090812683, 27.68164693365221],
        [85.34958064556122, 27.680233674546376],
        [85.34961551427841, 27.679527038135966],
        [85.34963294863701, 27.679173718216415],
        [85.34963965415955, 27.67882989823954],
        [85.3491300344467, 27.678497359753933],
        [85.34833073616028, 27.678055557057107],
        [85.3477030992508, 27.677685011481945],
        [85.34742951393127, 27.677480735819717],
        [85.34582018852234, 27.67640234401577],
        [85.34501552581787, 27.67586314412168],
        [85.34459710121155, 27.675599481530597],
        [85.34359395503998, 27.67480611458053],
        [85.34282147884369, 27.674036495626662],
        [85.3426605463028, 27.673863093076964],
        [85.3424996137619, 27.673670687186004],
        [85.3423547744751, 27.67370869331478],
        [85.34217238426208, 27.673637431812473],
        [85.341979265213, 27.673627930275323],
        [85.3418183326721, 27.67368493948585],
        [85.34133553504942, 27.673941480565038]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Balkumari"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.3413462638855, 27.673912976030437]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Sukedhara"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.34576654434203, 27.727830245914127]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Dhumbarahi Chowk"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.3441572189331, 27.732103730912865]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Chappal Karkhana"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.34212946891785, 27.73517104017694]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Bhabhateni, Maharajgunj"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33869624137877, 27.739187850221853]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Narayangopal Chowk"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33656120300292, 27.739282808478443]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Chundevi"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33424377441405, 27.737412115579346]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "T.U Teaching Hospital"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33091247081757, 27.73470572637005]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Nepal Police Academy",
      "description": "Talimkedra"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.3289544582367, 27.73283970308218]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Pabitra Workshop"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33086955547333, 27.729686858314775]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Russian Embassy"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33093392848969, 27.728727691662566]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "3. No Gate",
      "description": "Baluwataar"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33068180084229, 27.726116056515774]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Baluwataar"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.3309178352356, 27.724646390680565]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Bhabhateni"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33125579357147, 27.7196436801267]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Police Headquarter"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33039212226868, 27.71709356279219]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Balmandir"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.3294587135315, 27.714514891889714]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Naxal"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32667994499207, 27.714942300122082]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Naag Pokhari"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32485604286194, 27.71359833303317]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Manakamana Marg"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32376706600189, 27.7128384856546]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Hattisar"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.3221845626831, 27.71197890192642]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Hattisar/Kamalpokhari"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32202363014221, 27.710734630607693]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Putalisadak"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32288193702698, 27.706498302755374]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "New Plaza"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32273173332214, 27.700936685417314]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "New Plaza"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32376170158386, 27.700675458162724]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {},
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32889544963837, 27.699340814612487]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Hanumansthan"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32753825187682, 27.693284842577803]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Bhatbhateni, Anamnagar"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.32877743244171, 27.69259610291114]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Baneswor",
      "description": "In fron of BICC Hall"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33566266298294, 27.690432482106786]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Sankhamul"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33609986305237, 27.68820469162307]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Minbhawan"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.33864796161652, 27.68762279856196]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Koteswor"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.34891009330748, 27.678369094638953]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#7e7e7e",
      "marker-size": "medium",
      "marker-symbol": "",
      "name": "Nepal Yatayat Station, Chabahil"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [85.34401774406433, 27.722207983788774]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "stroke": "#a87a6c",
      "stroke-width": 2,
      "stroke-opacity": 1,
      "type": "return"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [85.32500088214874, 27.71380729013424],
        [85.32499015331268, 27.714158717083265],
        [85.32500088214874, 27.714443657021473],
        [85.32504916191101, 27.714742843155406],
        [85.3251564502716, 27.715094267089952],
        [85.32527983188628, 27.715284225502],
        [85.32539784908295, 27.715417196193584],
        [85.32594501972197, 27.715212991136262],
        [85.32620251178741, 27.715127509835945],
        [85.32654583454132, 27.715037279501804],
        [85.32680869102478, 27.714956547034323]
      ]
    }
  }, {
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
      "stroke": "#a87a6c",
      "stroke-width": 2,
      "stroke-opacity": 1,
      "type": "return"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [85.3271359205246, 27.714890061427965],
        [85.32750606536865, 27.71631474412121],
        [85.3278923034668, 27.71774415705227],
        [85.32858967781067, 27.717611189197914],
        [85.32950699329376, 27.717350001869082],
        [85.33039748668669, 27.717112558300027]
      ]
    }
  }]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```